# WriteVideo Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, timer

I am trying to write some code to take images from a uEye camera and store them in an avi file. Basically a time lapse. The idea is take 10 images every 10 minutes. I wrote a function with the a timer and a callback function to take the images and store them in the avi file created.

This is how the main function looks like:

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'RGB24_2048x2048');

vwObj = VideoWriter('timelapsevideo.avi', 'Uncompressed AVI');
vwObj.FrameRate =1;
open(vwObj);

t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'FixedRate', ...
    'Period', 2, 'TasksToExecute',2, ...
    'TimerFcn', @timelapse_timer);

start(t);

delete(t);
```

The timer is not specified for 10 pictures every 10 minutes but this is not my problem.

The callback function looks like this:

function timelapse_timer(vid, event) %#ok

```
utilpath = fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox', 'imaq', 'imaqdemos', 'helper');
addpath(utilpath);

vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'RGB24_2048x2048');

start(vid);

img=getdata(vid, 1, 'native', 'numeric');

% imwrite(img, 'example.jpeg')

vwObj = vid.UserData;

writeVideo(vwObj, img);

close(vwObj);

end
```

I can take one image and write it so the getdata works. The problem is that it does not write it in the avi file created giving me the next error:

> Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-1'
>
> Undefined function 'writeVideo' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

I have done changes like converting the image taken to gray scale but still the same problem.

Thank you in advance for your help
Juan

Comment: You're trying to get the handle to your `VideoWriter` object from the `UserData` property of your input video object, but I don't see you ever assigning it to `UserData` in the first place. Use [MATLAB's Debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to make sure you're using the correct inputs to `writeVideo`.